# Can a Raspberry Pi 4 run at 75hz at 1080p resolution?

Tags: screen

I have a 1080p monitor which can run at 60 and 75 hz and I was looking to buy a raspberry pi. Can the latest raspi 4b+ support this combination of refresh rate and resolution? I was not able to find the answer to this anywhere and would like to know it before I buy one and test it myself.

Comment: You can find lots of information here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md

Comment: 1080p at 60 Hz is a standard mode which will work out of the box. 75 Hz should be possible to set up via `config.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

yes it does work I have a 75hz monitor and it has the option to do 75hz and I have a refresh rate monitor built into my gaming monitor that says it is running at 75hz and it feels soooo smooth so yeah it will work but I am using twister OS, its the best use it